# RestKit: JSON mapping doesn't work Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, web-services, restkit

I use the RestKit framework to connect to a rest webservice. 
How should the mapping look like if i want to have the resultlistEntries.
I've got a JSON-response like this:

```
{
"resultlist.resultlist": {
    "paging": {
        "numberOfHits": 69978,
        "numberOfPages": 3499,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "pageSize": 20
    },
    "resultlistEntries": [
        {
            "@numberOfHits": "69978",
            "@realEstateType": "7",
            "resultlistEntry": [
                {
                    "@creation": "2013-01-15T16:36:00.000+01:00",
                    "resultlist.realEstate": {
                        "@id": "68014527",
                        "@xsi.type": "search:Office",
                        "calculatedPrice": {
                            "currency": "EUR",
                            "marketingType": "RENT_PER_SQM",
                            "priceIntervalType": "MONTH",
                            "value": 4.5
                        },
                        "commercializationType": "RENT",
                        "courtage": {
                            "hasCourtage": "YES"
                        },
                        "floorplan": "false",
                        "netFloorSpace": 155,
                        "price": {
                            "currency": "EUR",
                            "marketingType": "RENT",
                            "priceIntervalType": "MONTH",
                            "value": 697.5
                        },
                        "totalFloorSpace": 155
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

and the following RestKit Code

```
NSString *pathPattern = @"resultlist.resultEntries";
NSString *keyPath = @"resultEntry";

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = 
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping 
                                            pathPattern:pathPattern 
                                                keyPath:keyPath   
                                            statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

the result is the following:

```
2013-01-15 16:49:00.102 RestKit_final[31840:c07] 
Failed with error: No response descriptors match the response loaded.
```

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`pathPattern` is used to specify an endpoint where the response descriptor will be used. For example, `@"/hotels/premium"` as a pathPattern will mean that the response descriptor will not apply if you call `@"/hotels/cheap"`. You can set this to `nil`, but I always like to keep my response descriptors as specific as possible.

The `keypath` for the `resultlistEntry` array in the JSON response would technically be `resultlist.resultlist.resultlistEntries`, but you may have some issues with the `resultlist.resultlist` part. I would suggest changing your API to return simply `resultList` then your required keypath will be `resultlist.resultlistEntries`.